# Find path that has specific sub directory

Tags: grep, find, filter

Consider path in a directory structure

```
/A/B/C/D
/A/B/C/E
/A/B/O/P
```

now if I want to list all path which has sub directory C in it, then can it be done through grep?
Expected output:

```
/A/B/C/D
/A/B/C/E
```

I tried using grep and find but could not achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

While ka3ak's answer works, find comes with a parameter "-path" so you can simply use

```
find . -type d -path "*/c/*"
```

-path seems also a bit faster:

```
[hexathos:~/test] $ time find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/c/.*"
./a/b/c/d
./a/b/c/e

real    0m0,013s
user    0m0,010s
sys 0m0,000s
[hexathos:~/test] $ time find . -type d -path "*/c/*"
./a/b/c/d
./a/b/c/e

real    0m0,012s
user    0m0,007s
sys 0m0,003s
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need `find` for this:

```
find A -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/C/.*"
```

For the following directory structure

```
A                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
└── B                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    ├── C                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    │   ├── D                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    │   └── E                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ├── C1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    │   └── E                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    └── O
        └── P
```

it would return:

```
A/B/C/E
A/B/C/D
```